# Test two variables in the same script

Tags: variables, awk

Question :

I'm breaking my teeths under this:

```
awk -v full=wc -v empty=wp '{
     ...blablabla...
     if ($4==full) stop=yes
     if (stop==yes && $4==empty) exit
     ...blablabla...
     }'
```

The code works well (I mean, I get an output) if I don't declare the two variables `full` and `empty` at the beginning, and use instead the values of these in the script. If I only use the first variable in the script, I get the same output. But if I only use the second variable, I get no output at all.

Comment: Please try and show a complete example and explain the expected and actual output. "blablabla" and "it works" and "it doesn't work" are useless for anyone trying to understand what you want the script to do.

Comment: The part of the script you showed doesn't print anything, so it's surprising that you consider "it doesn't work" when you get no output.  You also haven't said what the input is!  I didn't ask for the whole script, just a minimal example that can actually be studied that reproduces your problem. Your question is poorly worded, unclear and shows lack of effort. -1. Must try harder.

Comment: Nobody questioned your English, which is quite good. @JonathanWakely raised issues which are directly on point, and likely to a) make it harder for you to get the right answer to your question, and b) make it less likely for other SO users to answer future questions from you.  SO isn't usenet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens when the variables are expanded. A portion of the awk body goes from:

```
' ... if ($4=='$full') ...'
```

to

```
' ... if ($4==wc) ...'
```

Since `wc` is a "bare word", awk thinks it is a variable and substitutes it's value (empty string), so you get this:

```
' ... if ($4=="") ...'
```

When you're building your awk script, you need to be aware of quoting strings in awk. You need:

```
' ... if ($4=="'$full'") ...'
```

However, it is much more elegant to pass values with awk's `-v` option as you have done.